# Exception found trying to logout from ftp in Mule 4

Tags: mule, mule4

I am getting Exception found trying to log out from FTP warning while deleting file FTP operation. After the Reconnection strategy, It is working fine. But I have to handle this exception as it is lower down performance.

Comment: Please share the complete text of the exception from the log and the configuration and usage of the FTP connector from the application (in XML).

Comment: Also please clarify the performance impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expiration Policy with MAX Idle Time set to 2 min and auto-closes the FTP connection, thus avoiding the logout error.

Comment: I tried this one but I'm still encountering the logout exception warning.